PyBind11 Module ImportError: cannot dynamically load executable
I'm attempting to generate a python module using pybind11, which compiles properly (I think) but when loading the module I get a "cannot dynamically load [position-independent] executable". If I don't use -no-pie I get position-independent as well, but I'm not sure if that's better or worse in this case. My understanding is that I do want a dynamic library but it's not being compiled like that? I'm running python3.10 and g++11.4.0. I'm fairly new to C++ so I have no idea if it's a trivial issue or not.
I've tried changing g++ compiler flags such as -no-pie, -fPIC, -rdynamic, but I don't really know what they do and don't seem to have changed anything except -no-pie. I haven't been able to find any threads describing this problem.
Here's my Makefile:
#!/bin/bash

INC=$(shell pybind11-config --includes) -I$(shell pwd)/include
LIB=$(shell python3-config --ldflags)
FLAGS=-fPIC

default: main

main:
        # @echo ${INC}
        g++ $(FLAGS) $(INC) $(LIB) pymodule.cpp otherfile.cpp -lpython3.10 -o test$(shell python3-config --extension-suffix)

pymodule.cpp:
#include "otherfile.h"
#include <iostream>

#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>


void fn() {
        std::cout << "fn works" << std::endl;
        fn2(); // from otherfile.cpp
}

int main() {
        std::cout << "main works" << std::endl;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(test, m)
{
    m.doc() = "Test";

    m.def("fn", &fn);
}

otherfile.cpp
#include "otherfile.h"
#include <iostream>

// Has many other includes in actual file

void fn2() {
        std::cout << "fn2 works" << std::endl;
}

include/otherfile.h
#ifndef OTHERFILE
#define OTHERFILE

void fn2();

#endif

test.py
import test


You're focusing on the wrong part of the error. You need to add -shared to your final link stage (and remove the main function) to produce a dynamic link library. You should also strongly consider using pybind's CMake support instead of randomly inputting flags.
